# How to scale an application to multiple companies

Tags: php, architecture, extensibility, configurability

The company I'm working for has an ERP software, or better, a home incident management application, for repair companies which in turn attend to requests from insurance companies.

There are a lot of repair companies using our application, which was copied from a standard and customized for their particular needs.

That's a nightmare for updating and scaling it!

I'd like to know about good approaches to optimizing this: same application instance with inherited classes for each company? would interfaces fit here? How could we deal with a centralized application in different servers? We don't want to use only one server for all.

Comment: This is a huge question, and either requires a lot of inside knowledge to help, or you need to simplify down your question. How "customised" is each application, are these customisations basic such as forms, or do they alter the core workings of the app in some way? are there any data protection issues that requires in-app/in-store firewall-esc separation of data? 

The very basic answer to your questions is that it is possible, but each piece of the pie needs to be considered here.

Comment: Hi Lee. All the applications may have a lot of modifications, but in general the core of it remains the same. what do you mean with in-app/in-store firewall-esc separation of data?

Comment: Hi Luis. The seperation of data refers to whether you can share a scaled database between all clients or not. For example the users table. Could you have all users in the same database for every site (i.e. shared store) with programming logic to restrict what users can access which sites, or would you have each sites database separate, and switch between databases depending on the requested site. There are huge data protection issues involved in choosing your preferred path, especially if this is enterprise/corporate level software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Java, Spring and OO for configurability & extensibility. Applications normally have "config" tables with properties, but the need for configurability normally extends beyond what properties can easily configure.

This is really the domain where OO programming languages, full control of the container, and powerful frameworks -- such as Spring, for configuration/dependency injection & Hibernate for ORM mapping -- come into their own.

You can "try" to do all this in PHP, but with 20+ years experience in all languages -- and no disrespect intended -- for a serious product you might need to consider moving towards a serious language.

As to what you'll actually need to do:

1. Configuration table & admin UI for it. These are essentially key-value properties, which your application will use rather than constants, where variability is needed. *Caching these is essential for performance, so having control of the webapp at the server-level is important here.*
2. Strategy Pattern. Algorithms such as calculating tax, building an invoice or interfacing to external systems are implemented as strategies, which are pluggable & configurable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern
3. XML Bean Configuration/ Dependency Injection. For deployment & algorithm configuration. This layer selects, creates & configures your strategies enabling you to select & parameterize appropriate algorithms for your customer requirements. This is the modularity lives, that lets you you share most codebase between customers but plug in the necessary differences here. In Java we use Spring: 
   http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.3/reference/beans.html

Building actual software products, that perform & can be configured for diverse customer requirements, is hard. It requires a solid platform, real tools & a moderate chunk of design skills.

The separate issue, not directly related to configurability & strategies, is the *multi-tenant application* (what @Lee was mentioning). That's where an application runs multiple customers, with different settings, off the same server simultaneously. (I did major infrastructure work, architecture & upgrades on such an app recently). However it's a different question, more complicated still (but only somewhat so) and and not necessary to address in this topic.

My experience is that Java and C# are *fast and reliable* while PHP is *slow*, *less than highly reliable*, and tends to encourage *security vulnerabilities*. I do a lot of major applications (industrial, Government, financial, software products) with advanced requirements, systems integration & high-performance features -- from compact, to med-large to large-sized apps. So I'm pretty well versed in how to deliver multi-customer products -- and what platforms enable me to deliver good-performing, reliable apps successfully.

Comment: Just wondering here as I've had only a year in this field, what makes PHP not 'serious'?

Comment: Hi Thomas, well, you probably quit PHP years ago, when PHP was merely used to do things in the middle of HTML blocks all in a mess. PHP has changed a lot. Versions 5.4/5.5 are very OO focused. There are great frameworks, such as Laravel, or the pre-compiled framework (made with C) Phalcon PHP.
I've used Codeigniter myself, and shifting towards Laravel right now, but I can't get to figure out how to do such a thing like this, which implies more than a simple project/application.

Comment: See edit. I've detailed an effective & complete approach to implementing multi-customer & multi-requirement configurability for your app (and software products in general). I don't agree this is a "huge question", it's a straightforward architecture-level question which -- with the right tools & platform -- can be very effectively solved.

Comment: WordPress is an example of an application taking configuration & extensibility about as far as PHP probably can. Self-installing code is nifty for users.. even if dubious from the reliability side. Problem is, WordPress is pig slow. And competitors may enter your market in future! One of the big questions you're going to have to think about is, _is WordPress-level performance going to be good enough?_

Comment: @BeatAlex then there's the security issues -- PHP, as originally designed, makes vulnerabilities the easiest & most common form of code. Lack of prepared & parameterized statements is a big big one here.

Comment: Thanks for your edited reply Thomas. It's more clarifying. Do you know about any resources in the web about this in which go in depth? Regarding PHP, I didn't mention Wordpress at all. That's a CMS, not a framework, and follows quite a procedural programming model. Not the best example to speak about PHP, even though it's such a hugely spread web application (because of its simplicity).

Comment: Thanks @LuisMartin. You may be able to research these topics separately, but this is all architect-level knowledge and not widely shared or published. Good luck.